# Adding "PushLink" jar to my app to make it self-updating

Tags: java, android, jar, addition, self-updating

At first, I want to say that I'm beginner in Android programming.
I need my application to be self-updating so I was trying to add the jar file from http://push-link.com/ to my application to make it self-updating.

I've added the jar ([this one](https://www.push-link.com/PushLinkAndroid-2.0.3.jar)) to the classpath (copied jar file -> right click -> Build Path -> Add to build path...), I've added Internet permission to AndroidManifest.xml by pasting this code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

after this code:

```
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

and called PushLink.start method by writing:

```
PushLink.start(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher, 10, "myApiKey", true);
```

after this code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And now my application crashes at starts:

> 03-05 20:20:27.509: I/ActivityThread(26890): enter process activity
>   msg = 110   03-05 20:21:09.149: I/ActivityThread(26927): enter process
>   activity msg = 110   03-05 20:21:09.199: W/dalvikvm(26927):
>   threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc8a0) 
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   pl.defozo.gim1menager.PushLinkSetup: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   pl.defozo.gim1menager.PushLinkSetup in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/pl.defozo.gim1menager-1.apk]
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:663)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4274)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:132)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2109)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)   03-05
>   20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)   03-05 20:21:09.219:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4669)   03-05
>   20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   03-05
>   20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)   03-05 20:21:09.219:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)   03-05
>   20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)   03-05 20:21:09.219:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26927): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   pl.defozo.gim1menager.PushLinkSetup in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/pl.defozo.gim1menager-1.apk]
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)   03-05
>   20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)   03-05
>   20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:658)
>   03-05 20:21:09.219: E/AndroidRuntime(26927):  ... 11 more

How to implement it correctly?
Is there any tutorial which contains informations about push-link.com?
Any other idea how to simply make application self-updating?

Thanks in advance,
Defozo

Answer (score 0):

In the properties → build path → projects did you check your own project?

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLx_72qxK_0&feature=player_embedded#!) is a general tutorial for adding a different library but the set up is the same.

Comment: I watched this tutorial and I think this jar looks to be added alright.
I uploaded my project file:
http://speedy.sh/THVvC/SourceCodesFromWorkspace.zip

Comment: You cannot download from this url without registering an account.

Comment: Hmmmm...
There is reupload:
http://www.mediafire.com/?91r1o3tjbbxkl3a
or
http://uploading.com/files/2c4cbfea/SourceCodesFromWorkspace.zip/

Answer (score 0):

```
 > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 >     pl.defozo.gim1menager.PushLinkSetup in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data
```

the errormessage tells you that class pl.defozo.gim1menager.PushLinkSetup is not found.

if this class comes from your jar file make shure that in the "java build path" under "order and export" there is a checkmark bofor your jar to tell the buildsystem that the jar should become a part of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

May have a problem with package name

Use:

```
<manifest package="pl.defozo.gim1menager" ...
<application android:name=".PushLinkSetup" ...
```

or

```
<application android:name="pl.defozo.gim1menager.PushLinkSetup" ...
```